# React Native: highlighting substrings properly

Tags: react-native

I have a text and I would like to highlight some of its parts, like:

> This is a well-written paragraph of text.
>
> This **is a** well-written **paragraph** of text.
>
> ```
>    5-8           23-31
> ```

Highlights are defined as an array of arrays:

```
[[5, 8], [23, 31]]
```

How to convert source text (a string) into **renderable JSX item**:

```
(<Text>This <Hl>is a</Hl> well-written <Hl>paragraph</Hl> of text.</Text>)
```

the React Native way?

P.S. *Hl* is simply a JSX-macros:

```
const Hl = (props) => <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{props.children}</Text>
```

Answer (score 2):

Created a simple function that takes text and array of values to transform. Run the below snippet for example

```js
function transform(text,arr){
  let transformObj = arr.reduce((all, item) => {
    let st = `<Hl>${text.substring(item[0], item[1] + 1)}</Hl>`
    let rl = text.substring(item[0], item[1] + 1)
    var temp = {
      [rl]: st
    }
    all.push(temp)
    return all
  }, [])

  for (let item in transformObj) {
    let key = Object.keys(transformObj[item])[0]
    let values = Object.values(transformObj[item])[0]
    text = text.replace(key, values)
  }

  return text
  
}

var text = "This is a well-written paragraph of text."
var arr = [[5, 8], [23, 31]]
var result = transform(text,arr)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice algorithmic solution. But I was actually asking about how to convert a text into ReactNative renderable item, that includes hightlights. Replaces on text don't do it.